# On the proving of two logical statements $\exists y\forall x$ vs. $\forall x\exists y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, quantifiers

Statements:

A: $\forall x\in\mathbb R\exists y\in\mathbb R:(y^2-2xy+x^2 - 2x + 2y \leq 0)$

B: $\exists y\in\mathbb R\forall x\in\mathbb R:(y^2-2xy+x^2 - 2x + 2y \leq 0)$

Prove that statement A is true and disprove statement B

Can someone please help me with this question? I'm having a lot of trouble with these type of questions.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Put down what you have tried before asking for help

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to start. I just need something to get me going. It's like that for all of these questions with me...

Comment: Do you know what $\forall $ and $\exists$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you are dealing here with $\left(y-x+2\right)\left(y-x\right)$. Can
you find for an arbitrary $x$ some $y$ that ensures this expression to be not positive? If so then you solved the first case. Can you prove that for every $y$ some $x$ can be found such that the expression is positive? Then you solved the second case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for Part A**. The question asks you to show that for all $x$, we can find $y$ such that some expression involving $x$ and $y$ is sufficiently small. So, why not let $x$ denote a fixed but arbitrary constant, and use basic calculus to find the $y$ that minimizes that expression. You'll get an expression $y(x)$ dependent on $x$ that makes the expression as small as possible. Then, just note that to prove

$$∀x∈\mathbb{R}∃y∈\mathbb{R}:P(x,y)$$

it suffices to prove

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : P(x,y(x)).$$